# Migrate SSIS packages from MSDB to SSISDB in place

Tags: ssis

We have several server that are running SSIS packages stored in MSDB. I'd like to change that to use SSISDB instead. What's the easiest way to do this?

These are not pure SSIS servers, so I don't want to migrate to new boxes, this needs to be in place.

This is on my, nice to have list, so if it isn't relatively easy\low risk, it's not going to get done

The servers are running SQL 2017 enterprise

Comment: Easiest way to do it will be manually extract it from MSDB and manually deploy to SSISDB and change execution path to new location. Do you have lots of packages so you need automated solution?

Comment: [Migrate or Copy SSIS Package From Database MSDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1079814/migrate-or-copy-ssis-package-from-database-msdb)